# Facebook app id not validating

Tags: wordpress, facebook-opengraph, meta, app-id

I am checking the og metas of the wordpress I'm currently working on.  The problem is the app id meta on post pages is not been validated when I check it on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/, 
but its OK on the home page. What could be the problem?

Top page:
http://www.milu.jp/column/

Example for post page
http://www.milu.jp/column/?p=39